# Restrict user to open email link in-app browser

Tags: javascript, html, ios

We are sending a link in email . Is it possible to restrict user to open that in browser only not in in-App browser.
Because of mail app security policy I can not use JavaScript in html template which we are sending on mail. I tried with target="_blank" also .

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot dictate to a user what happens on their device when they click on an email link. This is determined by the settings that are in place on their client.

If your security requirements dictate specifics about how emails should be sent, then you need to control the entire experience surrounding sending an email (ie: you provide the textbox and controls to be used to send the message, and you handle the delivery of the email.